# My tkinter Entry's .get() function returns nothing, what should I do on my code to make it possible. Code Below:

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

def accountinfo1():
    a = nameentry.get()
    
    info1 = open("Account #1.txt", "w")
    info1.write(a)
    info1.close()

    messagebox.showinfo("Sign Up Process", "Registration Success") 
def newaccount():
    global newscreen
    newscreen= Tk()

    global nameentry
    nameentry = StringVar()
    
    labelname=Label(newscreen, text='Enter your Name:')
    labelname.pack()
    entername=Entry(newscreen, textvariable=nameentry)
    entername.pack()

    submitbutton = Button(newscreen, text="SUBMIT", command = accountinfo1)
    submitbutton.pack()
    
    newscreen.mainloop()
def main_screen():
    global mscreen
    mscreen=Tk()

    addaccountbutton = Button(mscreen, text="Add Account", width = '20', height = '2', command=newaccount)
    addaccountbutton.pack(padx=50,pady=50)

    mscreen.mainloop()
main_screen()
```

Comment: Try changing ` nameentry = StringVar()` to ` nameentry = StringVar(master=newscreen)` or replace the second `Tk()` with `Toplevel()`

Comment: Welcome to StackOIverflow! Don't hesitate to look at the [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the help center. For instance, that would be better if you could edit your title to make it shorter and move the extra information to the body of the question.

Comment: Also see [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: Thank you so much! TheLizzard. It works!❣️GodBless you

Answer (score 0):

Your `StringVar` is unnecessary. What you need to do is to make your entry global, so when you call `accountinfo1()`, you can get the value of your entry straight away without having to use a `StringVar`. Also use `Toplevel()` instead of a second `Tk()`.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

def accountinfo1():
    a = entername.get()
    
    info1 = open("Account #1.txt", "w")
    print(a)
    info1.write(a)
    info1.close()

    messagebox.showinfo("Sign Up Process", "Registration Success") 
def newaccount():
    global entername
    global newscreen
    newscreen= Tk()

    global nameentry
    
    labelname=Label(newscreen, text='Enter your Name:')
    labelname.pack()
    entername=Entry(newscreen)
    entername.pack()

    submitbutton = Button(newscreen, text="SUBMIT", command = accountinfo1)
    submitbutton.pack()
    
    newscreen.mainloop()
def main_screen():
    global mscreen
    mscreen=Tk()

    addaccountbutton = Button(mscreen, text="Add Account", width = '20', height = '2', command=newaccount)
    addaccountbutton.pack(padx=50,pady=50)

    mscreen.mainloop()
main_screen()
```

Comment: The is no point to the `newscreen.mainloop()` line. If you remove it, the code will run the same way. Also what if OP was tracing how the entry was changing using `<tkinter.StringVar>.trace`?